# No sound when receiving push notification

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

i am using `react-native-firebase v6` to handle the push notification. The problem is there is no sound played when the push notification received.

I have create a channel and set it to high priority since the default channel created by react-native-firebase has no sound. Here the code i  used in the **MainActivity.java**

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {    
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("notifid", "App notification channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    notificationChannel.setDescription("custom notification channel");
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 200, 400});
    //notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
  }
}
```

And here is the code to change the channel in **firebase.json**

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "messaging_android_notification_channel_id": "notifid"
  }
}
```

But the sound still not playing when the notification received.

Comment: Can you show where you handle the notification object?

Comment: @bored i think it's not related to how it handled. when the push notification received there is no sound. so it must be on rn-firebase settings or the android side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sound through setSound method. Using NotificationChannel class you can set sound for each channel separately and get it played on receiving particular notification. 
According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))

> Sets the sound that should be played for notifications posted to this channel and its audio attributes. Notification channels with an importance of at least NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT should have a sound. Only modifiable before the channel is submitted to NotificationManager#createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel).

You can either use system sound or get your custom sound place inside res folder and call it in the method signature accordingly. 
Just add the following line of code to set sound:

```
notificationChannel.setSound("sound.mp3",AttributesToSet);
```

Here AttributesToSet refers to [AudioAttributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes) class which you can use to provide further information about your sound file.

**UPDATE:**
To use default notification sound, you can use following snippet.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); //define this before building notification channel
```

Then use this uri in setSound method as:
notificationChannel.setSound(notification);

Comment: i am lack of android native side, if i want to use default notification, what constant should i use?

Comment: is this channel thing editable, i have tried changing the priority to default and set the notification sound. but when it's is installed the allow sound still disabled in notification settings :-/

Comment: To make things synced, just make sure that you restart your packager and reinstall your app when introducing / changing native code.